# Why does this code throw "'list' object has no attribute" error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does this throw

> queue_length = items_in_queue.get_jenkins_queue_len(items_in_queue)
>   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_jenkins_queue_len'

```
class JenkinsQueue :

    def get_jenkins_items_in_queue(self) :
        logger.info("Starting...")
        with open('/Users/praveen-bhasker/datafile.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
            data = json.loads(data_file.read())
            return data["items"]


    def get_jenkins_queue_len(self, data):
        print(data)
        return


jenkinsqueue = JenkinsQueue()
items_in_queue = jenkinsqueue.get_jenkins_items_in_queue()
queue_length = items_in_queue.get_jenkins_queue_len(items_in_queue)
```

Comment: because `data["items"]` is a `list`. Everything loaded through `json` is a basic python object (list, dict, string, int). Cannot be a complex object with custom methods.

Comment: also note: your `get_jenkins_queue_len` should just call `len(data)` so it's not really useful to create an instance method. Maybe you should revisit your OO conception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As get_jenkins_queue_len() is implemented in class JenkinsQueue, you need object of that class to call so you have to replace 
`queue_length = items_in_queue.get_jenkins_queue_len(items_in_queue)`
with
`jenkinsqueue.get_jenkins_queue_len(items_in_queue)`